# Trying to border the last row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select the last row of my table and use an outside border around the whole row up until the last column. Here is my Code

```
Cells(Application.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
```

Before I had

```
Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
```

My second line of code only bordered the first cell. I need it to outside border all the cells in the row. I have tried different things like turning it into a "range" to only get an error. These are my closest attempts. I do not get an error but it does not do what I need it to do.

Thanks,

G

Comment: Are you trying to create a border up until the last column in the entire sheet? Or the last column in your data set?

Comment: Create a range object that includes the entire range for which you want to set the border (eg: the last row).  Then use the `BordersAround` property of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in both of your code attempts, you are only selecting one cell.  Because you are using the `Cells` method, you are only selecting a single cell.  You need to use `Cells` in conjunction with the `Range` object to get a multicellular region.

Assuming your data starts in cell A1 on Sheet1, here is working code:

```
Sub DrawBorder()

    Dim rngBottomRowStart       As Range
    Dim rngBottomRowEnd         As Range
    Dim rngDataUpperLeftCell    As Range

    Set rngDataUpperLeftCell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    With rngDataUpperLeftCell
        Set rngBottomRowStart = Sheet1.Cells(.End(xlDown).Row, .Column)
        Set rngBottomRowEnd = Sheet1.Cells(rngBottomRowStart.Row, .End(xlToRight).Column)
    End With
    Sheet1.Range(rngBottomRowStart, rngBottomRowEnd).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to all that answered. All your inputs worked but this one was the most comprehensive to me.

Comment: Sorry, one issue that this is having is that it borders the entire row of the spreadsheet and not just the table.

Comment: The code works for me.  Did you change the code at all?  If so, how?  Does your data start in cell A1 or did you change the code to reflect a different start location?  You will probably have to account for special circumstances like a table with only one row (excluding the header, so only two rows on the spreadsheet) or only one column.  I would need to see your data and any changes you made to the code to say for sure why it's not working for you.  You could post an edit to your original comment if you want me to take a look at what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

- Find the table
- Find the last row
- Optionally clear any existing borders
- Create a range object encompassing the last row (or whatever part you want to border).
- Use the `BordersAround` property to draw the borders

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub BorderAroundBottom()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim rFirst As Range, rLast As Range, rTable As Range

    'Need to know where table starts
    Const ColHdr As String = "ColA"

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")

'Find first cell of the table
'Can hardcode this if known
With WS.Cells
    Set rFirst = .Find(what:=ColHdr, after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                    searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If rFirst Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "First Column Header not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rFirst.Column).End(xlUp)
    Set rLast = .Cells(rLast.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

    Set rTable = .Range(rFirst, rLast)

End With

With rTable
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    .Rows(.Rows.Count).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
End With
End Sub
```

---

[image]